# AWS Lambda unable to locate user profile on CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cli

Following this [tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/setup-awscli.html) to setup CLI and trying to invoke `AWS Lambda` with the following command

```
aws lambda list-functions --profile xxxxx
```

But all I get is

> The config profile (xxxxx) could not be found

I've created a user with username `xxxxx` on `AWS IAM` and I've successfully logged in AWS using this `xxxxx` as I can see `xxxxx@accountID` after I logged in.

I've also checked @ `C:\Users\myWindowUser\.aws`that there is below two files

```
config
credentials
```

May I know which part could have gone wrong?

Comment: @downvoter, care to share any feedback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `profile` argument isn't used to specify a username. It is used to specify a [named profile](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-multiple-profiles.html) that you have created in your local credentials file. You probably haven't created any named profiles in the credentials file. If you created the credentials file via the `aws configure` command, then you will only have a `default` profile in your credentials file. If you only have a `default` profile then you shouldn't be trying to specify a `profile` parameter.